# Variables and Context in JS OOP events handling

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to make object that after invoke will create elements with events handling. I wanted to put everything in this one object, so events called by these elements are also in thsi object. The problem is that I'm not sure if that is optimal of if I should do it other way.

```
"use strict";
var addFunctionBlock = (function(uarea){
var target = document.getElementById(uarea); // VS this.target

this.init = function(){
    for(var a = 0; a < 5; a++){
        this.button = document.createElement('button');
        this.button.onclick = this.eventHandler;
        this.button.style.width = "50px";
        this.button.style.height = "20px";
        target.appendChild(this.button)
    }
};  

this.eventHandler = function(ev){
    target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ev));
};
this.init(); 
});
```

Was trying to make events with `this.target` but events called after click on button will point to button not to object inside which is function, so i swaped it to variable `var target = ...`, but I'm not sure it that is properly (and that is also one of questions should I do it this way or maybe it is bad). Can it interfere with other variables in global scope (did tests and passed but probably i missed something)? When should I use variables in objects and when use (this) context? Did reserch on internet but found nothing about that ;/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've annotated your code on some particular problems. Hope it helps you understand what you are actually building; in contrast to what you probably want to build.

```
//you don't need the round brackets around, only when you are creating a self-invoking-function
var addFunctionBlock = (function(uarea){
    var target = document.getElementById(uarea); // VS this.target

    //you (probably) don't call this function with the new-keyword,
    //and the scope is also not bound to some object
    //so, `this` points to the global Object ( `window` )
    //  1. you pollute the global namespace
    //  2. every call will overwrite the definitions of the ones before.
    this.init = function(){
        for(var a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            //each iteration you assign a new button to the same property on the same object.
            //each iteration you overwrite the value with a new one.
            //if you want to keep a reference to (all) buttons, push them to an Array
            this.button = document.createElement('button');
            //well here is the problem/misunderstanding. functions are executed with the scope of the object they are called on,
            //not the object they have been defined on; in this case: the button.
            this.button.onclick = this.eventHandler;
            this.button.style.width = "50px";
            this.button.style.height = "20px";
            target.appendChild(this.button)
        }
    };  

    //if you want your `eventHandler` to memorize to whom he belongs, you schould bind his scope
    //this.eventHandler = function(){ ... }.bind(this);
    //now this function will always be called with this pointing to `this`.
    this.eventHandler = function(ev){
        target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ev));
    };

    //what do you need an init-function for, if you instantly call it?
    //why not just execute the code?
    this.init();
});
```

Why do you need some `this`-object? What about this code? Does it fit your needs?

I think you might be out of the Java-corner, and don't know anything else than Classes ;)

```
function addFunctionBlock(uarea){
    var target = document.getElementById(uarea); // VS this.target

    //eventHandler encloses the `target`-variable from this particular function-call,
    //and therefor you can always access it; like a private property.
    function eventHandler(ev){
        //first open the dev-tools of your browser,
        // then you can see the logs.
        console.log(target, ev.target);

        //better than this here
        //target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ev));
    }

    for(var i = 0; i<5; ++i){
        var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.onclick = eventHandler;
            button.style.width = "50px";
            button.style.height = "20px";

        target.appendChild(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks I call it with: 'var aa = new addFunctionBlock(area);' etc. so I have multiple instances of this same object. That is why I wanted to make it OOP style. About array I knew forgot it in example program :). Thanks for this function(){}.bind() method! Full code you can see on my github: https://github.com/underscorejasiu/elearning/blob/simple-drag-n-drop-game/pickndrop.js

Answer (score 0):

You could refer this to understand :- 
http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: ok, no problem .You can use this context if  your code is too cpmplex otherwise you can go for variable